# is there any way or package by which we can perform filters(searching) on custom raw sql query in django?

Tags: python-3.x, django, django-models, django-filter, django-database

I read the following document:
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/topics/db/sql/

In the models there are lots of filter lookups available like: `field__gt`, `field__lt`, `field__range`, and `field__contains` but i want to use these as raw sql like suppose:

```sql
SELECT * 
FROM customers 
WHERE customers.name like '%name%' and age < 30 and status IN ('active','pending')
```

Here :

- `customers.name like '%name%'` where name would be user input so I want to protect it from sql injection as well as filter it using `%` operator
- `age < 30`: 30 would be user input, and want to perform `<` `>` `=` also
- `IN ('active','pending')` I want to pass list of string using the `IN` operator

Is there any proper way/package available by which we can run raw sql preventing sql injection as well as filtering data using the `%`, `IN`, `<`, `>`, and `=` operators.

Comment: Yes of course : follow [this link](https://docs.djangoproject.com/fr/2.2/topics/db/sql/#performing-raw-sql-queries) for more details

Comment: @Rvector , There is only https://docs.djangoproject.com/fr/2.2/topics/db/sql/#passing-parameters-into-raw, instead of how to filter using % wild card express, IN operator, >, < operators.

Answer (score 0):

How about using the Django ORM? (This would be the proper way)

```py
Customer.objects.filter(name__contains=“name”, age__lt=30, status__in=[‘active’, ‘pending’])
```

Assuming table/column names and models/fields match up, that will result in the exact query you’re looking for with all of the security you want. If you really need to execute a raw query, then @Rvector gave you the docs you need.

Comment: What if you wanna run a complex query including inner, left joins, grouping on multiple tables

Comment: Depends on the query honestly. Django’s ORM, though lacking in arguably many ways, is ***not*** simple.

Comment: is there any package which can compose filter (where clause) in raw sql query by using those __gt, __lt __contains. so i can pass user input directly into it.

Comment: I’m confused by the question. You can either use the ORM in its full capacity or you can use raw sql (you could technically use both, but why). Both will accept user input. Just make sure you properly escape params if you go the raw sql route

Comment: something like 
RawQueryObject.where("field","=",userInput)
RawQueryObject.where("field","like",userInput)
RawQueryObject.where("field","in",userInputList)
in raw query

Comment: That’s not a raw query. That’s an ORM with different syntax.

Comment: That said, you’re probably looking for: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/models/querysets/#extra